# parsing errors when launching two robots from the same urd.xacro file

Tags: ros, roslaunch, urdf, xacro

I'm trying to launch two panda robots from the same urdf file but I'm stuck as is giving me parsing errors when I launch two robots together. If I try to launch one it works but not with two (I commented the part in the urdf.xacro code). How can I workaround this issue?

my launch:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

  <!-- Gazebo & GUI Configuration -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="true"/>
  <arg name="world" default="$(find franka_gazebo)/world/worldTable.world"/>
  <arg name="gazebo"      default="true" />

  <!-- Define arguments to be passed to dual_panda.urdf.xacro -->
    <arg name="use_gripper" default="true" />
    <arg name="x" default="0" />
    <arg name="y" default="0" />
    <arg name="z" default="0" />
    <arg name="roll" default="0" />
    <arg name="pitch" default="0" />
    <arg name="yaw" default="0" />

    <!-- World launch -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world)"/>
        <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
        <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
        <arg name="headless"    default="false" />
    </include>

    <!-- Spawn dual panda -->
    <param name="robot_description"
         command="xacro $(find franka_description)/robots/dual_panda/dual_panda.urdf.xacro
                  gazebo:=$(arg gazebo)
                  hand:=$(arg use_gripper)
                  xyz:='$(arg x) $(arg y) $(arg z)'
                  rpy:='$(arg roll) $(arg pitch) $(arg yaw)'">
  </param>

  <node name="spawn" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-param robot_description -urdf -model panda"/>

</launch>
```

my urdf.xacro:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="panda">

  <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/franka_robot_2.xacro"/>

  <!-- Name for this robot -->
  <xacro:arg name="arm_id" default="panda_1" />

  <!-- Should a franka_gripper be mounted at the flange?" -->
  <xacro:arg name="hand" default="false" />
  <!-- Positional offset between $(arm_id)_hand -> $(arm_id)_hand_tcp [m]. Only used when hand:=true -->
  <xacro:arg name="tcp_xyz" default="0 0 0.1034" />
  <!-- Rotational offset between $(arm_id)_hand -> $(arm_id)_hand_tcp [rad]. Only used when hand:=true -->
  <xacro:arg name="tcp_rpy" default="0 0 0" />

  <!-- Is the robot being simulated in gazebo?" -->
  <xacro:arg name="gazebo" default="false" />
  <!-- If `gazebo` arg is set, to which frame shall $(arm_id)_link0 be parented. Empty string for not fixing at all -->
  <xacro:arg name="parent" default="world" />
  <!-- If `gazebo` arg is set and `parent` not empty, what position offset between `parent` & $(arm_id)_link0 -->
  <xacro:arg name="xyz" default="0 0.5 1" />
  <!-- If `gazebo` arg is set and `parent` not empty, what rotation offset between `parent` & $(arm_id)_link0 -->
  <xacro:arg name="rpy" default="0 0 ${-pi/4}" />

  <!-- Define offset for panda_1 and panda_2 -->
    <arg name="offset_y" default="0.5" />

  <xacro:franka_robot arm_id="panda_1"
                      joint_limits="${xacro.load_yaml('$(find franka_description)/robots/panda/joint_limits.yaml')}"
                      hand="$(arg hand)"
                      tcp_xyz="$(arg tcp_xyz)"
                      tcp_rpy="$(arg tcp_rpy)"
                      gazebo="$(arg gazebo)"
                      parent="$(arg parent)"
                      xyz='0 0.5 0.501'
                      rpy="$(arg rpy)">
  </xacro:franka_robot>
```

```
  <xacro:franka_robot arm_id="panda_2"
                      joint_limits="${xacro.load_yaml('$(find franka_description)/robots/panda/joint_limits.yaml')}"
                      hand="$(arg hand)"
                      tcp_xyz="$(arg tcp_xyz)"
                      tcp_rpy="$(arg tcp_rpy)"
                      gazebo="$(arg gazebo)"
                      parent="$(arg parent)"
                      xyz='0 -0.5 0.501'
                      rpy="$(arg rpy)">
  </xacro:franka_robot>

</robot>
```

and my franka_robot_2 (is the same as the original panda file):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <xacro:macro name="franka_robot" params="arm_id joint_limits parent:='world' xyz:='0 0 0' rpy:='0 0 0' hand:=false gazebo:=false tcp_xyz:='0 0 0.1034' tcp_rpy='0 0 0'">

    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/utils.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/franka_arm.xacro" />

    <xacro:franka_arm arm_id="${arm_id}" safety_distance="0.03" gazebo="${gazebo}" joint_limits="${joint_limits}"/>

    <xacro:if value="${hand}">
      <xacro:include filename="$(find franka_description)/robots/common/franka_hand.xacro"/>
      <xacro:franka_hand
          arm_id="${arm_id}"
          rpy="0 0 ${-pi/4}"
          tcp_xyz="${tcp_xyz}"
          tcp_rpy="${tcp_rpy}"
          connected_to="${arm_id}_link8"
          safety_distance="0.03"
          gazebo="${gazebo}"
       />
    </xacro:if>

    <!-- Define additional Gazebo tags -->
    <xacro:if value="${gazebo}">

      <xacro:if value="${parent != ''}">
        <!-- Gazebo requires a joint to a link called "world" for statically mounted robots -->
        <xacro:if value="${parent == 'world'}">
          <link name="${parent}" />
        </xacro:if>
        <joint name="${parent}_joint" type="fixed">
          <origin xyz="${xyz}" rpy="${rpy}" />
          <parent link="${parent}" />
          <child  link="${arm_id}_link0" />
        </joint>
      </xacro:if>

      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface" />

      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface" />

      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint3" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint4" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint5" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint6" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
      <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_joint7" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />

      <xacro:transmission-franka-state arm_id="${arm_id}" />
      <xacro:transmission-franka-model arm_id="${arm_id}"
         root="${arm_id}_joint1"
         tip="${arm_id}_joint8"
       />

      <xacro:if value="${hand}">
        <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_finger_joint1" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
        <xacro:gazebo-joint joint="${arm_id}_finger_joint2" transmission="hardware_interface/EffortJointInterface" />
        <!-- Friction specific material for Rubber/Rubber contact -->
        <xacro:gazebo-friction link="${arm_id}_leftfinger" mu="1.13" />
        <xacro:gazebo-friction link="${arm_id}_rightfinger" mu="1.13" />
      </xacro:if>

      <gazebo>
        <plugin name="gazebo_ros_control" filename="libgazebo_ros_control.so">
          <controlPeriod>0.001</controlPeriod>
          <robotSimType>franka_gazebo/FrankaHWSim</robotSimType>
          <robotNamespace>/{arm_id}</robotNamespace>
        </plugin>
        <self_collide>true</self_collide>
      </gazebo>
    </xacro:if>
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```